# Why isn't the last element being iterated over in this extended ArrayList <Integer> class?

Tags: java, arraylist, extends

I am trying to extend ArrayList  with a simple class that shows and updates a total every time a value is added. Why is it that iterating through this list in the manner that I have done below only allows it to iterate through everything but the very last element added to this ArrayList?

Why is it that the following shows my total to be 6 when it should be 13?

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Test2 {

    public static void main (String [] args){
        IntStruct ints = new IntStruct();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(5);
        ints.add(7);
        }
    }

class IntStruct extends ArrayList <Integer>{
    private int total;

    boolean add (int i){
        setTotal();
        return super.add(i);
    }

    void setTotal(){
        total = 0;
        for (int i : this){
            System.out.println("Adding " + i + " to our total..");
            total = total + i;
        }
        System.out.println("The total is now " + total);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Add it to the list with `super.add`, then call `setTotal`, then return what `super.add` returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `setTotal()` before you call `super.add(i)` to actually add the item, so the latest item isn't present when you compute the new total.

Try this:

```
boolean add (int i) {
    if (super.add(i)) {
        setTotal();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question, but it would be more appropriate not to iterate over the list in order to calculate the total, e.g.

```
class IntStruct extends ArrayList <Integer>{
    private int total = 0;

    boolean add (int i){
        return super.add(i);
        total += i;
    }
}
```